# Glide not showing image to CircleImageView Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, android-glide

I am using glide to load an image to a CircleImageView. But the images is not showing. I am using a List Adapter class.

```
class ListAdapter (private val myDataset: MutableList<Aplaca>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val name = itemView.name
        val pic = itemView.pic
......

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = myDataset.get(position)
        holder.name.setText(current.getMyName())
        val imgTxt = current.getImg()
        Glide.with(holder.pic.context).load(imgTxt).into(holder.pic)
    }
```

I also tried with `.apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())`

Here is my CircleImageView code:

```
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
```

And yes, I have Internet-permission.

Comment: What is `imgTxt`? Is it a URL?

Answer (score 0):

As first, try to set image with out glide, if work, try to set image to normal imageview with out and with glide, else if this two method work I no idea

Answer (score 0):

**Try Using**

1. Use normal imageView instead of CircleImageView in XML.
2. Use property RoundedCorners(180) it will make it circular.

**Try Code**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YelpViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = myDataset.get(position)
    holder.name.setText(current.getMyName())
    val imgTxt = current.getImg()
    Glide.with(context).load(imgTxt).apply(RequestOptions()
    .transform(CenterCrop(),RoundedCorners(180))).into(holder.pic)
}
```